# Check if site is up or down

Tags: php

I have problem with this script if i check http://google.com/ or other website is not work and with http://stackoverflow.com or cnn.com is work...

```
$url = 'http://google.com/';

function urlExists($url=NULL)
{
    if($url == NULL) return false;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

if(urlExists($url))
{
    echo "ok";
}
else
{
    echo "no";
}
```

I have test `@fopen` and not work too

Website like google have blocker ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change:

```
if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300){
```

to:

```
if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<303){
```

The reason is that many sites use a `301 Moved Permanently` by default as well as `302 Found`.

Comment: Thanks with google is ok but with other website i have code 403 with this is ok ? if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<=403) ?

Comment: You might as well go up to 404 (although it really depends on intent of the script). You could also do something such as `if($httpcode=200 || $httpcode=301 || $httpcode=403)`, etc. Here's the status codes: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 0):

You are curling `http://google.com` which responds with the response code `301` to redirect visitors the `http://www.google.com`. In your logic, the `301` response code is considered offline.

You will need to adjust the URL you are checking, adjust the logic to accept this response code, or add the code below to make cURL follow redirects.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

it should probably read

```
if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<400){
```

Instead Of

```
if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300){
```

Otherwise, a redirect would be regarded as “server down”.

With the above change, the result for `http://google.com` is `ok`